# Always focus mouse cursor in particular div in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a div **"wtb_wrapper_middle**" in middle of my web page.

For that div only scroll able in web page. In left and right div are not movable, it fixed in my web page.

So I want to mouse always focus on that particular div wherever my mouse clicked or mouse hover. Means when i use keyboard up or down button at that time that particular div only should be scroll.

Is there possible in JQuery.

My code is like below.

```
<div id="wtb_wrapper_inner">
    <div id="wrapper_left">
       ....
       ....
       ....
    </div>
    <div id="wtb_wrapper_middle">
       ....
       ....
       ....
       ....
    </div>
    <div id="wtb_wrapper_right">
       ....
       ....
       ....
    </div>
</div>
```

In from above html code "wtb_wrapper_middle" area only scrolls in my web page.

I have tried the below

```
window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById("wtb_wrapper_middle_inner").focus();
};
```

In this code is focus only on page load, but if clicked mouse in somewhere else, at that time also that middle area should be scroll. That is not working.

My Ajax callback function like below

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "search.php?ajaxrequest=yes",
    data: query_string
 }).done(function( data ) {
     $(".wtb_p_loader").remove();
     $("#wtb_wm_listing").append(data);
 });
```

I'm appending return success data into the di **wtb_wm_listing** which is i have placed inside of main div **wtb_wrapper_middle**

Anyone help me to make it success..

Comment: Try `document.body.onkeydown = function(e){
    document.getElementById("wtb_wrapper_middle_inner").focus();
};`

Comment: Thanks @anu. Its Perfectly working for me.

Comment: I will add it as an answer then

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using css position: fixed; 
The two outer divs are fixed to the screen regardless of scroll position. Then the central div scrolls regardless of where the mouse pointer is. You can use top and bottom to fix the full height of the screen, then left and right to fix each on either side.
You can still interact with content in the fixed outer divs.
And the Html is

```
    <div class='left'>
    <a href='#'>Hover to check the  mouse focus and scorll</a>
</div>
<div class='center'>
   //some long content
</div>
<div class='right'>
</div>
```

Css for doing this action.

```
a {
    color: #000;
    display: block;
    font-family: arial;
    margin: 10px;
    text-decoration: none;  
}

a:hover { 
    background-color: #f03055;
    color: #fafafa;
}

p {
    color: #fafafa;
    font-family: arial;
    line-height: 24px;
    margin: 0 0 25px 0;
    padding: 0 2%;
}

.center {
    background-color: #97c;
    height: 2000px;
    margin: 0 25%;
    width: 50%%;    
}

.left {
    background-color: #7c9;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 25%;
}

.right {
    background-color: #7c9;
    bottom: 0;
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 25%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: to filter out input elements

```
document.body.onkeydown = function(event){
   var e = event || window.event,
   target = e.target || e.srcElement;

   if (target.tagName.toUpperCase() == 'INPUT') return;
   document.getElementById("wtb_wrapper_middle_inner").focus(); 
};
```

this will move focus to your middle div whenever `keydown` event occurs.

Comment: In that case i have an input box in above of the div in body, when i try to edit that input box i could't make it

Comment: Updated my answer to filter out input elements. You can do the same for `textarea` if you have one in your page.

Comment: This will be work for ajax display content also rite? Because inside of that div i'm appending some ajax return html contents. After ajax completed, the focus is not working for me for that div

Comment: I have tried `$("#wtb_wrapper_middle_inner").focus` after append the data into that div. But its not working.

Comment: wrap the focus event within a `setTimeout()` function with a delay of 200 millisec. Some times focus works that way, not sure about the core reason though. let me know if that helps

Comment: Hmm in that case, you need to create a fiddle or post your code to get help. I want to see the ajax callback function code

Comment: I have given my ajax callback function in my question. Please have a look and help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129215/discussion-between-anu-and-vignesh-kumar).